# Get Text from an Edit Control (Pure Win32 API)

Tags: c++, winapi, controls, edit, gettext

I've been trying to get this to work for like ages but with no avail (sad face).

```
int iChars = GetWindowTextLength (GetDlgItem(handle,ID))+1; // Room for '\0'
char* pstrText;
pstrText = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*iChars);
if (pstrText != NULL) {
    //GetWindowText (GetDlgItem(handle,ID), pstrText, iChars);
        GetDlgItemText(handle,ID,pstrText,iChars);
}
return pstrText; // Memory gets freed after it returns
```

Working example:

```
char* MWC::System::TextBox::GetText(){
    int len = SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
    char* buffer = new char[len];
    SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)len+1, (LPARAM)buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Even if you reassing the pointer the memory still gets deleted so result will still point to a deleted memory. Also, the size of the pointer will be 32/64 bits depending on the plaform you are running. Fouth parameter of function GetDlgItemText has to be iChars.

Comment: Yeah well , thats not what's causing the function not to work properly.

Comment: "Not working" is not good enough for us. How does it fail. Be precise. We can't see your screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `wParam` parameter is wrong here:

```
SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)len, (LPARAM)buffer);
```

You should pass `len+1` because of the zero-terminator.

Answer (score 3):

You are freeing the memory before returning!!!

```
if ((pstrText != NULL) {
    GetDlgItemText(handle,ID,pstrText,sizeof(pstrText));
    free (pstrText); // Freeing memory Here!
}
```

You must provide a way for the client to free when its no longer needed...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Alright Thank you! Since pstrText is a local variable Its memory is supposed to be cleared after the function returns (right?). I removed free(pstrText) though now the program returns nothing.

Comment: pstrTest is a local variable. The variable gets destroyed when it comes out of scope but the memory remains allocated until you call free() on that memory. You have to figure out a way to free the memory when it is no longer needed.

Comment: What about the second example? It's returning nothing as well!

Comment: Third parameter to SendMessage must be len+1. Everything else looks good, are you sure that "handle" is valid?

Answer (score 2):

You already free the memory pointed to by `pstrText` before you return. You should return a string object that can actually contain the text and frees it automatically on release. Or you'll have to ask the caller to allocate memory for the string, but then you are just wrapping the API.

Comment: Thank you for noticing :P , though the problem still persists!

Comment: You need to free `pstrText` after you read/displayed/copied it (otherwise you'll have a memory leak). I think you'll be better of learning some C/C++ memory basics before you proceed.

Comment: It's a temporary variable so the memory gets deleted after the function returns.

Comment: And you return `result` instead of `pstrText` that's why you don't get anything sensible from it.

Comment: You still free `pstrText` before you return, allocation on the heap is never temporary.

Comment: What about the second example i wrote?